# Kinetic energy in cosmology?

Tags: gravity, general-relativity, expansion, hubble-constant, thermodynamics

Spacetime expands at an accelerated rate due to the Hubble flow. In many papers that I've read, objects coupled to the Hubble flow are treated as if they have some velocity and kinetic energy associated with it. Usually, that object would just keep gaining "speed" as the accelerated expansion of the universe would separate it from everything else at sufficiently far distances.

However, can there be any situations where this kinetic energy coming from the Hubble flow can be transformed into some other type of energy (thermal, electromagnetic, electric, gravitational, mass...etc)?

Comment: The "Hubble flow" just refers to the average particle (e.g. galaxy) motion associated with cosmic expansion. The Hubble flow doesn't accelerate cosmic expansion. Any kinetic energy in the Hubble flow is just kinetic energy of the particles moving with the Hubble flow.